# Finding diameter of graph using BFS

Tags: graph-theory, breadth-first-search

Algo to find diameter of graph is as follows:

1. Run BFS on any arbirtray vertex and remember the last node visited (say t)
2. Run BFS from t and rememver the last node visited (say t')
3. shortest distance between t and t' will be the diameter of the graph.

This is what I learned and it worked fine until I found the following graph:

```
A------G-----C------D  
|  
E------F------B
```

If I run BFS from `A`, I get `AGECF"DB"...`, and BFS from `B` gives `BFCEDGA....`, `so d(B,A)=3` should be the diameter.

But if I run BFS from `A` as `AGECF"BD"` and than run BFS from `D` which gives `DCBGFAE`, `d(D,E) = 4` should be the diameter

What went wrong? Doesn't this algo always work?

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm will work only if you want to find diameter of an acyclic tree. If you want to find diameter of a graph, you can use [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)'s all pair shortest path algorithm. Then traversing the whole distance matrix, you can find diameter of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your algorithm is incorrect. Take a look at the discussion here:

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/194/the-time-complexity-of-finding-the-diameter-of-a-graph

In general, if you want to guarantee the diameter of a graph you need to do a BFS (Dijkstra in a weighted graph) from every state and then take the maximum over all searches. (Or compute the all-pairs shortest-path information and find the longest shortest path from that data.)

You can do better if you are in a directed tree, or in other special cases.